# How to avoid big switch statement with too many options

Tags: php

In a class I have a method which  contains mainly a huge switch statement ( about 250 lines!!!) which calls different methods depending from the input. 
Yes it works, but it is just plain ugly and I have the feeling that there should be a more elegant solution for this.

it looks similar to this:

```
   private function choosePartnerMethod($oST, $sPartner)
    {
        $oPartnerReport = null;
        switch ($sPartner) {
            case 'aertpa':
                $oPartnerReport = $oST->aertpa();
                break;
            case 'adrtsh':
                $oPartnerReport = $oST->adrtsh();
                break;
            case 'adwev':
                $oPartnerReport = $oST->adwev();
                break;
            case 'agft':
                $oPartnerReport = $oST->agft();
                break;
            case 'alan':
            case 'alanrs':
                $oPartnerReport = $oST->alan();
                break;
            case 'andfe':
                $oPartnerReport = $oST->anfe();
                break;
            case 'bsera':
            case 'bsrhes':
            case 'bshwet':
                $oPartnerReport = $oST->bsera();
                break;
                .... many many more...
            default:
                break;
        }//end switch
        return $oPartnerReport;
    }
```

If always one case would match one method I could call them dynamically like:

```
    $oPartnerReport = $oST->$sPartner();
```

But as you can see there are cases where more than one matches one method.

Has anybody an idea how to solve this nicer?

Comment: If the 250 different cases are hardcoded, there probably isn't a nicer way. If it's from a database or something, you could loop through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking at something like:

```
$partnersCollection = array(
   'aertpa' => array('aertpa'),
   'bsera'  => array('bsera', 'bsrhes', 'bshwet'),
   // ....... method => partners
);

foreach ($partnersCollection as $methodToBeCalled => $partners) {
  if (in_array($sPartner, $partners)) {
    return $oST->$methodToBeCalled();
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks good. I will give it a thought about the optimal setup for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially do something like this:

```
class PartnerMethod{

    private $partners = array(
                            'aertpa' => 'aertpa',
                            'adrtsh' => 'adrtsh',
                        );

    public function choosePartnerMethod($oST, $sPartner){
        if(in_array($sPartner, $this->partners)){
            return $oST->{$this->partners[$sPartner]}();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your example is not covering the case when multiple partners are matching the same method. Also, the parameters order for `in_array` method is wrong

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, noob mistake. No it doesn't cover multiple partners that are matching the same method, it was mostly for example's sake. I'm sure OP can improve on it. Or even better take your answer and mine and combine them.